# Why am I getting a "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"?

Tags: php, android, mysqli, fatal-error

I'm working in this project that is an Android login app. It fetches data from an online server.

The registration works and the database gets updated but the login does not work.
We are using JSON to parse data from the server to the app.

Here is my PHP code:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->bind_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } 
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.
```

Comment: Well, the documentation says, `$stmt->bind_result()` returns a `bool`. Therefore the error message is not surprising. You cannot call a method on a bool, since a bool is not an object. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: You can't use `bind_result()` here.  `bind_result()` lets you assign variables to each column returned, you are doing `SELECT *`, so that won't work.  If you have MySQLnd, then you can use `->get_result()`.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: **$stmt->fetch_assoc();** shoud be done after binding result variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is not the method you want here.  That method (which returns a boolean, by the way) lets you assign variables to the columns returned in your query.  Your query uses `SELECT *`, so you cannot use `bind_result()`.

What you want is to use [`get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).  This requires the [mysqlnd driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) to be installed.

```
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: thank you for the response,but how do i install it on a remote linux server ?

Comment: @SahilSethi: Depends on what distro it's using, but you probably need to install `php5-mysqlnd`.

Comment: have'nt yet figured a way out,will try contacting the hosting company in the morning. till then any other solution ?

Comment: the distro of the linux server is Debian,any solution on how to get it working?

Comment: I forget the name of the package, but try `apt-cache search mysqlnd`.

Comment: the hosting company is still trying to figure it out,in the mean time i'm running it on my localhost.